# Infinite series with the binomial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, binomial-coefficients

How can we prove that

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{n \choose k}}{n^{k}(k+3)} = e-2$  ?

The only thing that came to my mind was writing out a few terms to see where that could get me, but I'm not able to make much progres. Any help in the form of hints or a solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $\displaystyle\frac{1}{k+3}=\int_0^1 t^{k+2}\ dt$, you get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k(k+3)}=\int_0^1 t^2\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{t^k}{n^k}\ dt=\int_0^1 t^2\Big(1+\frac{t}{n}\Big)^n\ dt,$$
and the $n\to\infty$ limit of this is $\displaystyle\int_0^1 t^2 e^t\ dt$ which has the expected value.

Comment: I don't get how the second integral simplifies into the given expression, could you please provide a little more info?

Comment: Do you mean you are not sure why $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k(k+3)} =\int_0^1t^2\left(1+\frac{t}{n}\right)^n\, dt$?

Comment: @NikilKumar edited (do you see the binomial series?).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth yes

Comment: @metamorphy sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that...

Comment: @NikilKumar I mean $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k$ with $a=1$ and $b=t/n$.

Comment: @metamorphy ohhh that makes a lot more sense. Thanks!